# Is there a way to use a UIButton for text in a countdown timer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, timer, uibutton, uilabel

I'm a new in iOS Development and I am writing an app that has a countdown timer. I want the user to be able to tap on the time to set it so I used a `UIButton` as that seemed the easiest thing. I've seen questions on this site about using a 'UILabel' for the timer and using a tap gesture to detect the user touching the 'UILabel', but it seemed like most people suggested using a `UIButton`.

The problem I'm having is that I initialize the `UIButton` text to be 00:00 and then change it when the user selects the time. The timer is set to go off every .25 second (repeating) and the handler updates the text in the button each time it detects that the time has changed by at least 1 second.

The problem I am having is that in between updates to the `UIButton` text, the `UIButton` text reverts to 00:00. For example, if the timer is set to 10 minutes (10:00), then the `UIButton` text does this:
10:00 (at start)

00:00 (at about 0.5 seconds)

09:59 (after 1 second)

00:00 (after about 1.5 seconds)

etc

If I use a `UILabel`, then this does not occur. Is there something inherently wrong with using a `UIButton`  this way? Should I just use a `UILabel` and figure out how to do a tap gesture? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the code where I update the `UIButton` text (I'm using a notification event):

```
- (void)timerChangedNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    Timer *timer = (Timer *) notification.object;

    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@kGameClockTimer]) {
        NSInteger timeInMinutes = (timer.currentTimeInSeconds / 60) % 60;
        NSInteger timeInSeconds = timer.currentTimeInSeconds % 60;

        if ((self.lastTimeInMinutes != timeInMinutes) || (self.lastTimeInSeconds != timeInSeconds)) {
            self.lastTimeInMinutes = timeInMinutes;
            self.lastTimeInSeconds = timeInSeconds;
            // this label is to see if the same behavior happens using a label
            self.timerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02ld:%02ld",
                                            (long)timeInMinutes, timeInSeconds];
            self.timerButton.titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02ld:%02ld",
                                (long)timeInMinutes, timeInSeconds];
        }
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT:**
Based on some comments below, I changed the code when setting the 'UIButton' to be this:

```
[self.timerButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02ld:%02ld", (long) timeInMinutes, (long) timeInSeconds] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

That does get me closer in that I don't get the 00:00 in between updates, but the text still "blinks" between updates. I suspect it has something to do with the forState. Do I need to set the title for other states also?

**EDIT:**
Ok, I found a solution to my issue with the button "blinking". I had to add:
`[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];` in my code.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Sorry, I should have done that, but it was late and I was tired. I updated my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a button to present count down?

I think you can use the way below. I tried it and it works for me.

I have three properties

```
@property(nonatomic,assign)NSInteger time;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *smsButton;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSTimer *timer;
```

And then start the timer with a method:

```
- (void)smsButtonPressed :(id)sender {

self.time = 60;
self.smsButton.enabled = NO;
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(updateTime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

}

In updateTime method , you do this :

```
- (void)updateTime {

if (self.time == 0) {

    [self resetTimer];
}
[self.smsButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",self.time] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
self.time --;
```

}

Use methods above, I think you can achieve what you want to implementation.

May this help. :)

Comment: This was helpful. I did change my code and it doesn't go back to 00:00, but it still "blinks". Does setting the button to be disabled while the timer is active get rid of the blinking? I'll try that just to see if it has any effect.

Answer (score 1):

I set my button title like this, and it works properly without reverting. Perhaps, you are accidentally reverting it in your code?

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
[button addTarget:self
           action:@selector(action:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 220,40);

[button setTitle:@"string" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
button.titleLabel.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"string"     
attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor], NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:21.0f]}];
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be fine using a UIButton. But I think you're doing this

```
button.titleLabel.text = @"09:59";
```

instead of this

```
[button setTitle:@"09:59" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Thanks! I did try that, but I still get a "blinking" behavior. See my updated post.